# If Statement in jQuery XML Ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, if-statement

Can I add an IF statement to a XML query with jQuery?

My query is as follows.

```
$("#page_all").live('pagebeforecreate', function() {
    $.get('http://ontariosheep.org/mobile/data/data_all.php',function(data){
            $('.content').empty();
            $(data).find('market').each(function(){

        var $market = $(this);
        html += '<div class="ui-block-a">' + $market.find('lambs').attr('head') + '</div>';     

    }
}
```

I'd like to add an if statement on line 6. So that 'html+=' only happens if "$market.find('lambs').attr('head')" is set.

Is this possible, if so how?

*EDIT:*

All entries do have a head attribute BUT the ones without any head are blank like so head=""

Comment: Yes, you can add an "if" in there. You're just adding it to a function; the function is the anonymous function being passed as a parameter to the `each()` function.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an if statement, you can filter it before the `.each`:

```
$(data).find('market').filter(':has(lambs[head])').each(...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think because the entries without any head still say head="" with nothing inside. Can the filter be altered to account for that. Like filter, if lamb[head]!=""

Comment: Yes, `[head!=""]`. If that doesn't work, you'll have to rely on an if statement within the `.each`

Comment: @KevinB plz help me out in these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591761/how-to-compare-the-value-with-xml-data